# Como expor states do filho para o pai?

Tags: react

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber como solucionar este problema.

Tenho um componente filho que é como se fosse um menu. Ele contém botões e, atualmente - de acordo com o click nas funções que estão no componente pai - vai exibir outros componentes. Só que eu não quero que as funções abaixo fiquem no componente pai. Gostaria que tais funções ficassem no filho.

Funções:

```
 const onChangeActive = (event, value) => {
            setSelectionActive(value)
          }

const onChangeType = (event, value) => {
            setChartType(value)
}
```

Mas, se eu coloco no filho eu perco o acesso dos states e suas mudanças que preciso no pai. Os states são: `chartType` e o `selectionActive`. Por isso,  preciso dos estados dele - que neste caso são `chartType` e o `selectionActive` - acessiveis no componente Pai.

Componente Filho:

```
const Filho ={type, buttonActive, onChangeType = () => { }, onChangeActive = () => { } ) =>{
    
    return(
    <ToggleButton value={type} onChange={onChangeType}>
      <Button disabled={buttonActive===TABLE}>button 1</Button>
      <Button disabled={buttonActive===TABLE}>button 2</Button>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value={buttonActive} onChange={onChangeActive}>
      <IconButton>
        <Span title="chart" />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton>
        <Span title="table" />
      </IconButton>
    </ToggleButton>
    )}
```

Componente Pai:

```
         const Pai = () => {
           const [chartType, setChartType] = useState(1)
           const [selectionActive, setSelectionActive] = useState(1)
    
           const onChangeActive = (event, value) => {
            setSelectionActive(value)
          }
        
          const onChangeType = (event, value) => {
            setChartType(value)
          }
            
            return(
                  <Filho buttonActive={selectionActive}
                  onChangeType={onChangeType}
                  onChangeActive={onChangeActive} />
          {selectionActive === SELECT_CHART ? renderOpcao1() : renderOpcao2()}
           )
        
        }
```

Como eu consigo tirar essas funções `onChangeActive` e `onChangeType` do pai, deixar no filho mas no pai continuar com acesso aos states `chartType` e `selectionActive` no componente pai?

Comment: Você já chegou a ler a seção [Elevando o State](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) da documentação do React? Existe uma explicação relativamente bem detalhada que pode ajudá-la. :)

Comment: funcionou, obrigado !!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o context API, do próprio react. O fluxo de informações do react vai sempre de cima para baixo, de pai pra filho. Pra fornecer um estado a vários componentes, a partir do  context API, você deve criá-lo em uma hierarquia elevada. Ficou confuso né? Vamos por partes então.

1. O primeiro passo é criar um componente de contexto, onde vamos declarar métodos e fornecer valores que serão acessíveis globalmente:

Importamos o `createContext` e o `useState`, que é usado pelos métodos que você postou na questão, criamos um contexto, a priori vazio, e então o exportamos por padrão:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
const MyContext = createContext({});
export default MyContext;
```

2. Ótimo! Já temos o contexto criado, mas tem um detalhe faltando. Todo contexto precisa de um provider. É ele quem vai entregar as informações para todos os seus filhos. Um contexto sem um provider é como uma carta sem carteiro, então vamos criá-lo:

O provider é como um componente funcional qualquer do react. Vamos programar os métodos desejados e retorná-los a partir de `jsx`:

```
export function MyProvider({children}) {
   const [chartType, setChartType] = useState(1)
   const [selectionActive, setSelectionActive] = useState(1)
   
   const onChangeActive = (event, value) => {
        setSelectionActive(value)
   }
    
   const onChangeType = (event, value) => {
        setChartType(value)
   }

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{
                chartType,
                selectionActive,
                onChangeActive,
                onChangeType
            }}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

O que fizemos acima foi simplesmente transferir os métodos e variáveis dos seus componentes para outro e retorná-los dentro da prop `value` de <MyContext.Provider />. Tendo feito isso, agora poderemos acessar essas informações a partir de todos os componentes filhos desse provider. Considere então os seus componentes `<Filho />` e `<Pai />`, precisamos garantir que eles sejam filhos do provider. Para isso importamos o `MyProvider`:

```
import { MyProvider } from './caminho/relativo/myContext.js';

function index() {
    return (
        <MyProvider>
            <Pai>
                <Filho />
            </Pai>
        </MyProvider
    )
}
```

Tendo feito isso, todas as informações retornadas dentro do `value` do provider estarão acessíveis, mas para puxá-las precisamos usar o hook `useContext()`. Vamos supor que lá dentro do componente filho você queira acessar o método `onChangeActive`, para isso você primeiro importaria o hook e o contexto:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import MyContext from './caminho/relativo/myContext.js';
```

Depois, dentro do componente que quer acessar os dados, faríamos:

```
const { onChangeActive } = useContext(MyContext);
```

Se quiséssemos, além do `onChangeActive`, o estado de `chartType`:

```
const { onChangeActive, chartType } = useContext(MyContext);
```

É importante mencionar que, toda vez que um estado for alterado dentro do contexto, todos os componentes que usam esse contexto serão renderizados novamente, portanto, certifique-se de que o `provider` só tenha filhos que realmente precisam daquelas informações. Recomendo ainda [essa leitura](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) da própria documentação do react, que traz informações completas do fluxo de informações e ciclo de vida do context API. Você pode ver o desenvolvimento de um contexto do zero com [esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KISMYYXSIX8&t=3704s), que apesar de ser feito em react native, pode ser completamente reaproveitado pelo react.

Comment: Se a função tiver q ser compartilhada entre pai e filho contexto chega a ser matar formiga com bazuca, não acha?

Comment: É sim! fica avisado a quem interessar. A solução que você recomendou nos comentários da pergunta parece ser bem mais adequada, uma solução simples pra um problema simples.